# modify title style

Tags: css, sharepoint, sharepoint-designer

My objective is simple enough i just want to modify Title="New" to bigger size and color, i did apply with CSS but it doesnt works :(

```
<style type="text/css">
#g_523a7cea_3249_4ac1_b2bc_48efea016ad1
{
color: Blue;
}
</style>    


<WebPartPages:DataFormWebPart runat="server"
Description="" ListDisplayName="" PartOrder="2"
Default="FALSE" HelpLink="" AllowRemove="True" IsVisible="True"
AllowHide="True" UseSQLDataSourcePaging="True" ExportControlledProperties="True"
DataSourceID="" Title="News" ViewFlag="8" NoDefaultStyle="TRUE" AllowConnect="True"
DisplayName="Employee News" PageType="PAGE_DISPLAYFORM" FrameState="Normal"
PageSize="-1" PartImageLarge="" AsyncRefresh="False" ExportMode="All" Dir="Default"
DetailLink="" ShowWithSampleData="False" ListId="645a16cc-7fe6-4247-9800-2170e1479074"
ListName="{645A16CC-7FE6-4247-9800-2170E1479074}" FrameType="Default" PartImageSmall=""
IsIncluded="True" SuppressWebPartChrome="False" AllowEdit="True" ManualRefresh="False"
AutoRefresh="False" AutoRefreshInterval="60" AllowMinimize="True" ViewContentTypeId=""
InitialAsyncDataFetch="False" CssStyleSheet="" MissingAssembly="Cannot import this Web Part."
HelpMode="Modeless" ListUrl="" ID="g_523a7cea_3249_4ac1_b2bc_48efea016ad1"
ConnectionID="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" AllowZoneChange="True"
IsIncludedFilter="" __MarkupType="vsattributemarkup" __WebPartId="{A7755E5E-BE3F-4415-A163-BAA925625A0E}"
__AllowXSLTEditing="true" WebPart="true" Height="" Width="">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ID is for the DVWP. There ***is*** no style that you can apply to a whole DVWP in one fell swoop. Inside the DVWP there will be lots of other CSS classes for the different elements and they will be applied, overriding anything, even if you ***could*** use the web part ID for a CSS format.

A DVWP typically displays in a table. There are different classes and styles for TH, TR, TD and so on. If you want to change the appearance, then you need to tackle these classes for the table elements.

Answer (score 0):

replace script with style. script is for javascript. style is for css

```
<style type='text/css'> ... </style>
```

Comment: oops, typo, not that problems, but still thanks for notify =)

Comment: This is the major problem with ASP.Net. You have no idea what the HTML will look like until after the fact, and the Ids are always moving around. One thing you can do is use class names to access the elements.

Answer (score 0):

Render the page and see what ID you have in your HTML code, then apply the CSS. I'm almost sure that the ID is different, and that's why it doesn't work (happens almost everywhere, where web controls are being used, especially in ASP).

Comment: i did but it doesnt work as well, i am using IE10, i use F12 and mouse point to the element to retrieved particular ID and than i applied with my CSS but it doesnt work

Comment: There is a property of this component called `CssClass` - you may set it and create the same in CSS. And the specification: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.dataformwebpart_properties.aspx